# Is it possible to relate two entities without retrieving them from database in Entity Framework 4.1?

Tags: validation, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, data-annotations

Consider the following scenario:

```
public class Entity1
{
    virtual public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    virtual public String Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    virtual public Entity2 ReferenceToEntity2 { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
    virtual public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    virtual public String Name { get; set; }
    virtual public IList<Entity1> ListOfEntity1 { get; set; }
}

[TestClass]
public class EntityFrameworkTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_save_entity_with_reference_to_entity_with_required_fields()
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            var entity1 = new Entity1
            {
                Name = "My name",
                ReferenceToEntity2 = new Entity2 { ID = 1 } // reference (Entity2 with ID=1) already exists in the database 
            };
            db.Entity1List.Add(entity1);
            db.SaveChanges(); // exception here
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(DbEntityValidationException))]
    public void Should_not_save_empty_entity2_name()
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            var entity2 = new Entity2 { Name = "" };
            db.Entity2List.Add(entity2);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The first test is not passing. A DbEntityValidationException is raised, referring to the Name property of Entity2 when trying to save Entity1 instance.

I know that I could load entity2 instance by ID and associate it using entity1.ReferenceToEntity2 = db.Entity2List.Find(entity2Id), for example. But I actually have a entity with lots of references, and I don't want to go to database 10 times only to associate a foreign key!

Is it possible to insert a new entity1 instance into the database relating to an existing entity2 record without having to go to database to retrieve entity2?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Attach` is made for such a scenario:

```cs
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var entity1 = new Entity1
    {
        Name = "My name",
        ReferenceToEntity2 = new Entity2 { ID = 1 }
        // reference (Entity2 with ID=1) already exists in the database 
    };
    db.Entity2List.Attach(entity1.ReferenceToEntity2); // must be BEFORE Add
    db.Entity1List.Add(entity1);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

It tells EF that `Entity2` with `ID` = 1 already exists in the database. The entity is in `Unchanged` state after `Attach` and EF won't send any UPDATE or INSERT statement to the database for this entity. Just the foreign key in `entity1` is updated.